# Not able to share image in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-share

```
import { Share } from 'react-native-share';   
let options = {
message:"hello",
url:uri
}
Share.open(options);
```

> Im getting this error undefined is not an object evaluating _reactnative.Share.open

Comment: Did you install the library via `npm` and run `react-native link`?

Comment: @Dan yes I have installed using npm and linked using react native link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have converted downloaded image to base64 string and then passed in Share.options

```
import  Share  from 'react-native-share';  //Don't put curly braces  
let options = {
message:"hello",
url:uri // pass base64 string like this "data:image/gif;base64,"+ base64 string 
}
Share.open(options);
```

> This method worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try `import Share from 'react-native-share';` instead of `import { Share } from 'react-native-share';`

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i have tried your method error is gone but nothing is happening neither gives error nor shares the image